# My code in cf7 hook function is not executed. I put the code in wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, contact-form-7

I am using Contact Form 7 and trying to hook a function `'wpcf7_after_save'` with my own custom function `'my_wpcf7_after_save'` . To try , I am just putting some html tags to display on page.
But it looks like none if my code executes.

Initially , I tried to put just an error_log in my `'my_wpcf7_after_save'` function and it worked fine as it gave error log page.

```
function my_wpcf7_after_save (&$WPCF7_Con<tactForm)
{
    Echo "<html>";
    Echo "<title>HTML With PHP</title>";
    Echo "<b>My Example</b>";
    //your php code here
    Print "<i>Print works too!</i>"; 
}

add_action("wpcf7_after_save", "my_wpcf7_after_save");
```

I expected the HTML tags to be displayed on screen.

Comment: If you view it in a browser, the HTML tags will be parsed. If you want to see the HTML tags, you need to encode them using WP's [esc_html()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html).

Comment: add priority to your action:

`
 add_action("wpcf7_after_save", "my_wpcf7_after_save",99);
`

Comment: _“I put the code in wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/functions.php”_ - that you shouldn’t be doing in the first place - because this way, it will get overwritten when the plugin gets updated. Stuff like this belongs either in the functions.php of your own theme (not if you are using a pre-made one, same issue - in that case you should work with a child theme), or a custom plugin.

Comment: none of the solutions above worked. Suggestion my @misorude is good but can take it after code works.